# ASP.NET vnext overriding status code set in controller. Is this a bug?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm building a simple WebApi in asp.net vnext on a Mac. I've followed the example set in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6) but I'm having a problem where the response codes I set in my controller methods are being overridden

Take this method in my CrudController:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]CrudObject crudObject)
{
   var url = Url.RouteUrl("GetByIdRoute", new {id = 1}, 
       Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToUriComponent());
   Context.Response.StatusCode = 201;
   Context.Response.Headers["Location"] = url;
 }
```

When I curl this or hit it with PostMan I *should* see a 201 Created response and a Location header pointing me to another url. When I run this using kestrel I get the Location header but the response code is 204 No Content.

I assume this is the vnext middleware overriding my change to the status code. Is that right? If so, *should* it be overriding my status code or is it a bug? If it's the correct behaviour, how should I do a redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `void` returning action was [recently](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/a3c593bda931828405166fead6bb99d05b081af7) changed to not convert to `204` status code. However, for you scenario you could use the `CreatedAtRoute` helper method(this actually creates a `CreatedAtRouteResult`) which sets the `Location` header.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]CrudObject crudObject)
{
    return CreatedAtRoute(routeName: "GetByIdRoute", routeValues: new { id = 1 }, value: null);
}
```

Is it on purpose that you do not want to return the created object back to client? if not, you could modify the above code by not passing `null` to the `value` parameter.

Comment: It's relatively common to leave it up to the client to GET the object created in a POST.